# Access Google Workspace App Install Initial Authorization Grant

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

My Google Workspace Marketplace app requires Google Sheet scopes.

**My current flow:**

1. Click 'Install' in GWM listing page. During this step, Google displays the Google Sheets permissions the app requires and the user can approve. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/5vFzvZm) *(ideally I'd have access to this google sheet auth grant right here, but I don't)*
2. Navigate to my actual app website and click the 'Login With Google' button. At this step, I create their account in our system and log them in.
3. *(Redundant?)* Initiate the 'Authorize Google Sheets' flow where we request permissions, receive the refresh and auth token and save in our DB.

**My issue:** Users are being asked for Google Sheet permissions twice (step 1 and step 3), but I don't know how to access the grant from step 1.

Google requires splitting up Authentication and Authorization, as stated on [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview#separated_authentication_and_authorization_moments).

That means I need at least a 'Login' step and a 'grant google sheets permission' step.

However, in this GWM app install flow, in **Step 1** the user is already explicitly accepting the Google Sheet permission, but I'm not sure how to actually access that information.

I completely control **Step 3**, since this is within my app and I'm able to grab the refresh token etc, but **Step 1** is happening purely on the Google Workspace listing.

Is there any way to get access to the user's refresh token and access token based on the Step 1 permission grant? Are they actually giving access at this step, or is this just a visual cue to let users know that they will eventually be requested access?

Right now the flow feels like has a third totally redundant step and I think it could throw off some users.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By any chance, does your app use multiple Google Cloud projects?

Comment: @PatrickdC hey, no I'm just using one project

Comment: Add the images directly into the question body so the could be displayed inline.

Comment: How do you set the OAuth consent screen? Does your app is doing multiple calls to Google APIs using different OAuth scopes on each call? Does the Marketplace SDK Oauth scopes matches the scopes of the OAuth consent screen?

Comment: This is a great question - what exactly is happening in step 1? Are any kind of permissions granted and if so how to access them? Would be great to get this info!!